# How to to get animation on backstack fragment when i press back button?

Tags: android

I am working on fragment transition and i have custom transition animation.

```
public class FlipAnimation extends Animation {

public FlipAnimation() {
    setDuration(500);
}

public void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    t.getMatrix().reset();
    t.getMatrix().preTranslate((float) Math.random() * 6 - 3,
            (float) Math.random() * 6 - 3);
}
}
```

Now to set this transition to my fragment i used following method

```
public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    FlipAnimatio anim=new FlipAnimatio();
    return anim;
}
```

But this does not perform animation on back-stack fragment.How to to get animation on backstack fragment when i press back button? Also can anyone explain what is transit, nextAnim do and how to use them?

Comment: Suggestion: if you're going to do 3D effects, take a look at OpenGL ES.

Comment: no i just want 2D transition effect